# How can I split a large DLL into smaller DLL's?

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I have a large Visual Studio solution that contains many DLL projects. One of them "MyDLL" has dozens of source cpp files, and they often are interrelated via class hierarchy. The problem is that it takes a very long time to link this dll, so I want to create, say 2 dll's instead of one. That way, a change would only need link a smaller dll. Some of the source will be in MyDLLA, and the other in MyDLLB. I know I can't just move code to another project. If someone has advice or can point to a solution, that would be great.

I've tried creating a DLL project and moving files over, but I get "definition of dllimport static data member not allowed" on IMPLEMENT_SERIAL and the dynamics too. The classes are defined in a shared .h file, and all have AFX_EXT_CLASS attributes.

Comment: Dozens of source files is nothing. And the workload of  linking and loading with the DLL actually happens at run-time. So I really don't know what you are asking about here.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - DLLs to get "linked" at build time. But without understanding his project structure and link time dependencies, or what he means by "very long time", we won't know how to advise.

Comment: Is the problem that the error you mention only occurs when you try to split the original, single DLL into two, interlinked ones? If so, then you *probably* need to define your `IMPLEMENT_SERIAL` class as `__declspec(dllexport)` in one DLL and as `__declspec(dllimport)` in the other.

Comment: Maybe show us some of your header/source files where the error occurs.

Comment: Also, you **cannot** have the `IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC` macro for a class in the source file for a project ***except*** the DLL that actually defines and exports it.